# allow comma in phone number

Tags: regex, knockout.js, phone-number, knockout-validation

I would like to allow user to input comma in phone number field with Knockout Validation.

Is there any way to do this with Knockout? Currently I'm using `validPhone` to validate phone number like the code below:

```
this.PhoneNumber = ko.observable("").extend({
  required: { message: "Enter valid Phone Number" },
  validPhone: { message: 'Enter valid Phone Number' },
  maxLength: { params: 12, message: "Phone Number only allows 12 characters" }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to use the `pattern` [validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation), with a [regular expression](http://www.regxlib.com/).

Something like this:

```
this.PhoneNumber = ko.observable("").extend({
  required: { message: "Enter valid Phone Number"},
  maxLength: { params: 12, message: "Phone Number only allows 12 characters" }
  pattern: {
    message: 'This isnt a valid phone number',
    params: '^ your phone no. regular expression here  $'
  }
```

Comment: thanks, i guess its the only way i can do this, i struggle in writing a correct regular expression for my requirement

Comment: If you have an expression which nearly works, or even if you don't have it but you have an exact idea of the rules for a correct phone number, create a new question for it. You'll get help for sure.